# including other files into project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is it possible to include (import?) other files into the project.clj for a clojure project? (leiningen, specifically).

eg we have:

```
(defproject sample-clojure-cloudbees "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Sample clojure application - clojure 1.3 !"
  :some-key "some value")
```

It would be nice to define more things like :some-key in files other than project.clj.

Comment: Michael, can you clarify your intent? Would you simply like to include other projects that should be compiled? For that you can specify dependencies and those dependencies can have their own project.clj file. [Example](https://github.com/liebke/incanter/blob/master/project.clj) (Then see the other parts under the 'modules' directory).

Comment: See my answer for your other question,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738628/setting-a-project-property-to-a-non-literal-string-appears-to-not-work-in-leining/7739179#7739179

Comment: Paul - simply to have some config entries in an external file - in this case secrets which I will add to .gitignore - yet the project.clj will clearly "document" that you need to provide secrets by including this file. I do something similar with the play framework configuration, for example (if that means anything !).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason that defproject has to be a top-level form. You can construct a call to defproject by building up an argument list. The only catch is that defproject is a macro, so the straightforward "apply" function won't help.

```
(def extra-args (read-string (slurp "project-extension.clj")))
(eval (concat '(defproject sample-clojure-cloudbees "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT")
                extra-args))
```

Note that this is reading a file, then evaluating the elements from that file. Be sure you know where the file is coming from!

Comment: sure - in this case the external file is local and private settings. I am still tripped up by macros in the case of things like this, thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: sounds good - I wonder if others would consider this useful enough to be a function in leiningen itself?