# Setting a project property to a non literal string appears to not work in leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Take a simple project file:

(defproject sample-clojure-cloudbees "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Sample clojure application - clojure 1.3 !"
  :blah "hello")

When I read (get project :blah) I get "hello" string returned - as expected.

If I replace "hello"

:blah (slurp "some file...")

I get an error, Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to java.lang.String

It seems to not be evaluating things how I expect, any ideas?

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do here, here is the `defproject` source, maybe that helps? http://clojuredocs.org/leiningen/leiningen.core/defproject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

defproject is a macro it won't evaluate (slurp...) unless you tell it to,

replacing,

```
:blah (slurp "some file...")
```

with,

```
:blah ~(slurp "some file...")
```

will give you the content of the file.

Comment: Oh fantastic. I thought it was something like that. I will chalk this up as a lesson I won't forget ;) Oddly I am almost sure I saw it work in the past - I guess I probably wasn't expecting it to be a string and just didn't see an error like in this case when I went to use it.